# Strange duplicate sheet named "ThisWorkbook" that shouldn't be there and I can't get rid of

Tags: excel, vba

I saw this once before on a different workbook and I think I fixed that one the same way that I did this one but curious (for the next time) if there's a better way and also if anyone know what this is and why it happens. Sometime back in May '22, a new worksheet appeared in my VBA code. For the one referenced in the pic attached, Sheet81 (Bldg Ops) is a valid sheet that at one time was named Sheet8. The sheet is visible, all of my code is there and everything works fine with it. Sheet8 is now the added sheet that I don't need or want and in it is a duplicate of the code from Sheet81. Can't access it and can't delete it.
To fix it, I created a new workbook and copied all of the sheets and code over to it.
Anyone seen this before? Any ideas on the how & why it happens and an easier way to fix it when it does?

[image: VBA Project & Properties Window]

Comment: By can't delete it, you mean when you right click to delete via the tab? Have you tried deleting it programmatically?

Comment: Just noticed it's password protected...

Comment: Your project is likely corrupted. Consider exporting all code files while you can, and rebuild the worksheets in a new workbook.

Comment: Basically an Excel VBA project contains a `Workbook` and at least one `Worksheet` module; the only time I've seen more than a single component shown with the `Workbook` icon was with a corrupted host document.

Comment: Definitely agree on "export your code while you can" - that's almost always a sign that your file may soon be unusable.

Comment: Wasn't visible as a tab so no, couldn't delete it that way. Couldn't delete it from the VBA Project window either. Rob Bovey's Code Cleaner didn't clear either. Corrupted? Yes, to some degree but this is a shared file with 37k lines of code used by about a dozen users a day and got corrupted back on May 22nd (I just never noticed it until today). "Export your code while you can" is indeed a good policy but I run daily backups of my backups (which is why I could see when it happened). Again, mostly curious if anyone else has seen this happen.

Comment: Yes I've definitely seen it before, mostly on files with a lot of VBA wihich have gone though a largish number of edits to the code (x100 if using any ActiveX controls).  For some reason xlsb format seems to be a bit more durable in this respect.